# validator - minFiles

Tags: yii2

Yii2 validator has `maxFiles` property. But there is no `minFiles` in documentation.

The question is how can I create validation rule which checks for minimum quantity of uploaded files within pjax validation?

Answer (score 0):

there is 2 approach, 
you cant do it basically with js  !

but you can count your uploaded file by yourself in controller ,

```
if(count($model->file)<3){
...trow expectation ...
```

or you can use separate file upload button and make required for all of them .

Comment: Thanks, but I've contact developers already. They will add it into the next Yii version (2.0.14):
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/15417#issuecomment-354076637